# Cannot find Arduino IDE VS Code

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am using windows and I installed the Arduino IDE from Microsoft store, but I wanted to code everything in VS Code. When I want to run the program or select the board it just says this:

```
Cannot find Arduino IDE. Please specify the "arduino.path" in the user settings. Requires a restart after change.
```

How can I fix this, where can I find the arduino.path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install PlatformIO extension for VS Code. It has Arduino framework and it works with all possible boards, and then some.

Comment: Do I only have to install the extension or do I need to install it from their website too?

Comment: You can install it from Visual Studio Marketplace. Check this link: https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/integration/ide/vscode.html#quick-start

Comment: There are good youtube guides to walk you through. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dany7ae_0ks

Answer (score 1):

For me nothing could make Arduino IDE.app (2.0 beta) work. Switching to 1.8.6 (Arduino.app), putting that into my Applications folder (so the path is `/Applications/Arduino.app`) and setting the VSCode setting to:

```
"arduino.path": "/Applications/Arduino.app"
```

Fixed this error (and got me to select a board, which I was able to do with the command palette. Make sure to open the new non-beta Arduino.app and add any existing board manager jsons, such as esp32 in my case, that might have already been added to the beta Arduino. The libraries appear to already be in place.)

I also had to add this to my C/C++ settings for includePath:

```
${workspaceFolder}/**
/Users/<owen>/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp32/hardware/esp32/1.0.6/**
```

At this point "verify" began working. It was still pretty slow, and flashes the Arduino splash screen while running, so I'm now going to follow the platformIO advice and see if it's any better.

P.S. At first I also got an error about `[Warning] Failed to generate IntelliSense configuration` but think I fixed this by clicking the "don't show again" or similar on the popup that appeared in the lower left. (Similar errors show up on syntax issues, so could be related to that instead.)